i8kmon service in Dell Precision 3240 results in "no support for device type: power_supply
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]: No support for device type: power_supply
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     while executing
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]: "exec {*}$config(acpi)"
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     (procedure "read_ac_status" line 12)
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     invoked from within
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]: "read_ac_status"
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     (procedure "read_i8k_status" line 29)
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     invoked from within
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]: "read_i8k_status"
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     (procedure "check_status" line 5)
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     invoked from within
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]: "check_status"
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     (procedure "status_timer" line 8)
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     invoked from within
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]: "status_timer"
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     (procedure "main" line 9)
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     invoked from within
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]: "main"
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     invoked from within
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]: "if {$tcl_interactive == 0} {
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     main
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     vwait forever
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]: }"
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int i8kmon[442438]:     (file "/usr/bin/i8kmon" line 373)
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int systemd[1]: i8kmon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 29 12:50:21 fto-tc011.folksvfx.int systemd[1]: i8kmon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

